# creating A record for subdomain on AWS router 53 still get 403 forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a domain connected to AWS ec2([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) it works fine but when
I tried to create a subdomain(test.example.com) that point to the same ec2 as the parent domain I create an A record for the subdomain still gets 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Check your user permission at `https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/users/<your-aws-username>`. You must have one of the policies below attached to your account:

- AmazonRoute53AutoNamingFullAccess
- AmazonRoute53AutoNamingRegistrantAccess
- AmazonRoute53DomainsFullAccess
- AmazonRoute53FullAccess

If you don't have permission to attach one of these policies to your account, ask your administrator to do that.

Comment: I have the admin user And was able to add the A record successfully to router 53 but still returns 403 forbidden

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue for a slightly different case but the reason of the problem was probably the same. After fixing my problem, i reproduced your case as well.

It may be because of the cloud front that you are using.
You may need to add all the URLs that you are going.

please check you have provided a value for CNAME in Cloud front distribution settings.  (in your case you need to add two records there. One for main domain example.com and other for test.example.com).
Without this setting, cloud front distribution cannot be accessed via new  "**A record**".

[image]

if you have HTTPS access then your certificate must cover the subdomain. and maybe that is why the cloud front needs this setting here( To check it against the certificate).